# Theano's pkl_utils Dump Function not available in Theano 0.7?

Tags: python, pickle, theano

I want to save a model that I have trained.
Since it is using shared variables (like Weights, bias and so on) and since it should be readable on machines without Theano installed, I wanted to use the theano.misc.pkl_utils.dump() function.
However, it seems as if that is only installed in bleeding edge installations (the current github file looks different than my local one).

Is that really the case? And why is the description in the [docs](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/misc/pkl_utils.html#theano.misc.pkl_utils.dump) then?

I am using theano 0.7.0 and I'm seriously confused about this.
If that feature is not yet available (I can't install bleeding edge right now), what are other ways? I'm sure that I am not the only one trying to save a trained model the easiest way possible ;-)

Thank you a lot,

Roman

Comment: Was there an answer that has been deleted?
It said "pkl_utils is back again now in the development version."
If yes, why has it been deleted?

Comment: By now, the documentation linked says about `theano.misc.pkl_utils.dump`: "New in version 0.8."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you train your model using Theano, the parameters of the model will be eventually `shared` variables (probably a list of `shared` variables if the network consists of several layers). It is possible to *pickle* the list of `shared` variables and *unpickle* it later. However you might have problems to *unpickle* such variables in another machine, e.g. with no Theano installation or if you train in a GPU-capable machine that generates *CudaNdarrays* and then you want to load back the model in a non-GPU-capable machine. What I recommend you is the following: convert every shared variable of the list of parameters into a numpy `ndarray`:

`params_numpy = [numpy.asarray(p.get_value()) for p in params]`

where `params` is a list of `shared` variables. Then you can safely *pickle*/*unpickle* `params_numpy`.

Comment: This is what I finally did. But still, I feel that Theano lacks some wrapper functions here that make it easy to save and retrieve models, no matter what architecture they were trained on.
Google's rivaling framework Tensorflow is apparently able to do exactly this, even when the model was trained in Python and is loaded in C++.

Comment: You're absolutely true, it still lacks some functionality. However, note that Theano is developed by academics, whereas Tensor is developed by Google. And still, Theano has several advantages over TensorFlow, to my opinion.

This particular problem took me some time to find a solution, but as you see, the solution is pretty simple.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I was just a little surprised that there was nothing simpler around. But personally, I also prefer theano for now.